# How do I "View selected" in edit mode?

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut, navigation

My keyboard does not have a numpad so I changed the keymap for view selected to F as in Maya. The problem I'm having is  it doesn't work in edit mode when selecting Verts/Faces/Edges. I'm not sure if there's a different keymap I should edit or if view to selected should work in edit mode as well.

Comment: `F` in edit mode is for the *Fill* operator

Comment: Oh, so the keymaps do not override the existing ones. Thank you :)